# Using a 2nd router most effectively

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wired-networking, repeater

Hope this question is in the right place. I have an AT&T wireless modem & router, and an Asus RT-AC68. I had been running two separate networks, one for upstairs & one for downstairs. I've decided to switch to an access point/repeater model instead... First question, pros & cons of access point vs. repeater?

Second question, what do I need to do to use the same SSID on my Asus as I do for my AT&T router? I currently have it setup in Access Point mode, using the same SSID, and I'm unable to connecting to the internet through it... I've read that maybe I should use different channels?

Any guidance or feedback is appreciated!

Comment: How are is the access point connected to the router? do you actually have one cabled to the other? or do you have it configured a different way?

Comment: Hi @MaQleod, thanks for your response. I have them hardwired - one of the LAN ports on the AT&T router to the WAN port of the Asus device (access point/repeater/range extender).

Comment: Ok, I wouldn't use the WAN in this case. The Ethernet cable should be plugged into the LAN side on both devices.

Comment: Ok yeah I wondered about that. Can I have the same SSID in that case? Also, do you know the pros & cons of access point vs. repeater mode?

Comment: Yes, you can have the same SSID in that case (that is how I have it set up in my house). You should use access point mode if you are hard-wiring them. A repeater is meant to receive a wireless signal and then re-broadcast it, typically used when hard-wiring is not an option.